# Change enter to tab on inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, cakephp, form-submit

this is my whole code for a user login in cakephp:

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-2 col-md-4" id="login-box" style="text-align:center; margin: 100px auto 0 auto;">
    <div style="font-size:3em;text-align: center;">
        <i class="fas fa-table"></i> 
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center;font-size: 50px;font-family: 'Tahoma';">
    Fatables
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="header" style="text-align:center"><?php /*echo __('Authenticate');*/?></div>
    <br>
    <form action="<?php echo $this->Html->url( array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'loginmodal')); ?>" method="post">
        <div class="body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autofocus/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
            </div>          
        </div>
        <div class="footer">                                                               
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo __('Sign In');?></button> 
        </div>
    </form>
    <br/>
    <p >&copy; Fatables <?php echo date('Y');?></p>
</div>
<script type=“text/javascript”>
$("#username").on("keypress", function(e) {
    /* ENTER PRESSED*/
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        /* FOCUS ELEMENT */
        var inputs = $(this).parents("form").eq(0).find(":input");
        var idx = inputs.index(this);

        if (idx == inputs.length - 1) {
            inputs[0].select()
        } else {
            inputs[idx + 1].focus(); //  handles submit buttons
            inputs[idx + 1].select();
        }
        return false;
    }
});
</script>
```

As you can see I'm trying to change ENTER to TAB when pressed on my first input. Thing is we use a barcode scanner and in most cases form data will be filled by scanning so I want for determined inputs to change focus to the next one when enter pressed.

For some reason the above (and many more ways to do it) doesn't work, I don't know already if there's some problem with my syntax, or the selector or the function itself.

I'll appreciate some help over here.

Comment: So you want when `username` is `:focus` and user presses enter, the focus to go on the `password` input ? well...it works . See here - >https://jsfiddle.net/6w4uavhp/

Comment: Yep... Works for me too.

Comment: I see it working peachy on your fiddle but mine's not, my only guess is I have some kind of problem with the jquery call.I know it's not a good practice but I have it at the top of my layout, could this be the problem?

Comment: Yes, when your script runs, `$('#username')` will not find anything. Either move it to the end of your template or wrap it in `$(document).ready(function () { ... })`.

Comment: That was EXACTLY the problem For it to work I had to redeclare in my view the jquery script but figured it was not a nice solution so I did what you told me , wrap it into $(document).ready and works great. Just for knowledge why wasn't the script finding anything? It was already at the end.